# How to call yii user login in restfullyii?

Tags: yii, yii-extensions

I'm using yii user and rights for creating rbac in yii. i also uses restfullyii for Restfull services.

Now i need to merge the yii user and restfullyii, so that when i submit username and password in the client side(frontend), i should pass it through restfullyii to yii user and checks for the login credentials and return the appropriate message to the client.

When i tried the url with the Chrome Advanced Rest Client Application extension, i get the following error.

```
  <h2>Error 404</h2>

  <div class="error">
   Unable to resolve the request &quot;user/REST.POST&quot;.</div></div><!-- content -->
```

How to merge yii user and restfullyii extensions.

Comment: There seems to be something wrong in the POST URL parameter
&quot;user/REST.POST&quot;

Comment: can u give me a example on how to integrate restfullyii in login controller? so that i can call it. if there is some reference link which i can look into it, it will be greatfull.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your routes are wrong that's why you are not able to resolv any page.
check on configuration main.php your restfull yii routes first.
then try to get into the app using domain.me/index.php/api/